# Get JSon not returning posted object

Tags: mongodb, httprequest, postman, backend

I am posting an object to Mongo and am getting it but it is not returning what I posted.I'm new to backend and can't figure out what is going on none of the code is wrong so maybe it's with the server? I am not getting any errors I am getting to do added successfully

```
http://localhost:4000/todos/add
Post
{
      "todo_description": "My First Todo",
      "todo_responsible": "Sebastian",
      "todo_priority": "Medium",
      "todo_completed": false
}

get http://localhost:4000/todos

[
    {
        "_id": "5d19426d5c6af41120abab1f",
        "__v": 0
    }
]

//this is the function that adds the todo item
todoRoutes.route("/add").post(function(req, res) {
  let todo = new Todo(req.body);
  todo.save()
    .then(todo => {
      res.status(200).json(todo);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send("adding new todo failed");
    });
});

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Todo = new Schema({
  todo_description: {
    type: String
  },
  todo_responsible: {
    type: String
  },
  todo_priority: {
    type: String
  },
  todo_completed: {
    type: Boolean
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Todo", Todo);
```

todo is logged i get the information on the database
I expect this to get the information I posted

Comment: There are 2 `todo` variables -- the one used to invoke `.save()`, and the one used to represent operation result. Can you change the code and use different variable name?

Comment: BTW, why this question is related to "postman"?

Comment: Im using it to send requests and one sec let me try but i copied the code from the tutorial and it did not work either so i dont think it is a syntax error

Comment: Nah the todo lowercase is saving the new Todo inside of its variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your making your own JSON object with the value `"todo added successfully"`. If you want to return the newly created todo object use the code below,

```
todoRoutes.route("/add").post(function(req, res) {
let todo = new Todo(req.body);
todo.save()
  .then(todo => {
    res.status(200).json(todo); // <--- change to this
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(400).send("adding new todo failed");
  });
});
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: this help but doesnt solve why the data isnt saving correctly on the database

Comment: @TheGreenLightbulb sorry I couldn't understand your question, now I got the question. Can you show your Todo model?

Comment: Done the project was uploaded in december could it be depricated?

Comment: Figured it out had to change text to json application in postman Thanks Guys!